# How to access to the variables of the scope of a module called from the main module?

Tags: python, module, scope, configparser

I need to access to the variables of the scope of a module imported in the main module from other module.

In my app, I've some modules in the same directory.  One of these modules is a module that read a config_file.ini using configparser in order to load the configuration variables that use the other modules.

I don't want to import more than one time the module that manages the config_file.ini in order to avoid the issues of keep open twice the same file.

I'm not using functions nor clases in the module that manages the config_file.ini (only a function to update the file) but not to load the variables.

Graphical concept:

Module_A:

```
# !usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import module_B
import module_C
print(module_B.my_var)
print(module_C.my_var)
```

Module_B:

```
# !usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
my_var = "This is the Module B"
```

Module_C:

```
# !usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
my_var = "This is the Module C"
print(module_B.my_var)
```

I'm using Python3.x

Should I encapsulate them in a separate class?  I'm not experienced in OOP :-(

Answer (score 0):

Modules are only loaded once; subsequent imports *reuse the already imported module*.

In other words, just load your `config.ini` in your one module, then import the variables from that module into others.

Comment: But, how? In the examples above it throws exception in Module_C: NameError: name `'module_B' is not defined`

Comment: @Trimax: But that is only because `Module_C` should import `Module_B` if it needs access to it. That has nothing to do with loading a `config.ini` file though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Module_B.my_var in Module_C, you need in Module_C to `import Module_B`.